Can the $\forall$-elimination rule in Natural Deduction give a non-sentence?
The $\forall$-elimination rule is as follows:$\def\f{\phi}$
$$\frac{\begin{matrix}\vdots\\ \forall x\f \end{matrix}}{\f[t/x]} $$
where no constraints are placed on the term $t$. Does this rule not allow us to deduce non-sentences? As an example:
$$\frac{\forall x (x \times 1 = x)}{(x \times 1 = x)}$$
where I have substituted $x$ with itself, yielding a formula with a free variable.

Yes. As you can see from the rule you have written above, the universal quantifier must be instantiated by a term $t$ that can be: eitehr a variable, or a constant, or a "complex" term using a function symbol. The gist of the rule can be summarized with the dictum: what holds for all hold for any".Thus, if we have proved that "Every number is even", we can correctly deduce that "$n$ is even", "$0$ is even", "$n+0$ is even".

@MauroALLEGRANZA so when dealing with theorems of a theory (set of sentences) we are merely concerned with the formulas that can be deduced using natural deduction that are sentences?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, but we can also deduce $0\le x$, which is not a sentence as the variable $x$ is free, right?

@MauroALLEGRANZA sorry for the confusion. I was just asking if it counts as a theorem. It doesn't, right? As it is not a sentence

In "common" math practice, a formula with a free variable will be read as universally quantified. Thus, in practice $(0 \le x)$ will mean $\forall x (0 \le x)$.

Depends on the system. Some systems are ok to instantiate a universal with terms so that the result is an expression that contains one or more free vaiables. IN such systems you need to be careful how such statements are used in the context of the whole proof. Other systems only allow variable-free terms to be substituted for any variables. But those systems will need to figure out some other way to do a universal proof. In sum: don't think that every line in a proof is a stand-alone expression: they all have a role in the proof as a whole.

Yes.
As you can see from the rule you have written above, the universal quantifier must be instantiated by a term $t$ that can be: eitehr a variable, or a constant, or a "complex" term using a function symbol.
The gist of the rule can be summarized with the dictum: what holds for all hold for any".
Thus, if we have proved that "Every number is even", we can correctly deduce that "$n$ is even", "$0$ is even", "$n+0$ is even".
